# How to create CSR with emailAddress oneline?

Tags: openssl

I'm working on a [programming project that includes a bash script](https://github.com/jeff-puckett/openssl.csr.bash) that creates a certificate signing request.

The piece that's giving me trouble is:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.csr -subj "/CN=example.com/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com/O=MyOrganization/OU=MyUnit/C=US/ST=AR/L=Fayetteville"
```

Almost all the attributes look great, but for some awful reason, [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/req.html) is meshing the emailAddress line into the common name, which is resulting in invalid certificate issues in the browser.

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in example.com.csr
```

> ```
> verify OK
> Certificate Request:
>     Data:
>         Version: 0 (0x0)
>         Subject: CN=example.com/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com, O=MyOrganization, OU=MyUnit, C=US, ST=AR, L=Fayetteville
> ```

Note how it mashes them together:

> ```
> CN=example.com/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com
> ```

I'm expecting it to recognize the distinct attributes:

> ```
> CN=example.com, emailAddress=webmaster@example.com
> ```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww thanks for your attention, but this is for a bash script, which should be on topic for SO. plus, there's a ton of related questions already on here that didn't quite answer this question. if you can answer why it matters when the attributes are reversed, then that would be enlightening. thanks

Comment: Bash scripts are on topic, but you should probably ask questions about how to use unrelated commands on a different site. There are sites better suited for questions about how to use commands and how Distinguished Names are formed, and you will likely get better quality answers.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If I list the emailAddress attribute first,

```
openssl req -new -nodes -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.csr -subj "/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com/CN=example.com/O=MyOrganization/OU=MyUnit/C=US/ST=AR/L=Fayetteville"
```

then it seems to be able to distinguish it just fine.

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in example.com.csr
```

> ```
> verify OK
> Certificate Request:
>     Data:
>         Version: 0 (0x0)
>         Subject: emailAddress=webmaster@example.com, CN=example.com, O=MyOrganization, OU=MyUnit, C=US, ST=AR, L=Fayetteville
> ```

Comment: I just noticed the same problem. Thanks for finding a workaround.

Comment: I just tested OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018, the order for email address in the subject does not matter now. Your answer did show me how to add the email address to the subject. Thank you.

Comment: I got curious about this as well and it appears that is is a parsing problem in openssl.  I decoded the CertificateRequest ASN.1 file that is output when the CSR is created and that is correctly encoded.  It just appears that when openssl does the -text -noout it doesn't print the output correctly but this has no bearing on the internals of the certificate request.

Answer (score 2):

back in the day the email address could be part of the subject field.   there is a subjectAltName field for email address, which is what we all really should be using.  This caused some confusion in how the "/emailAddress=" part gets parsed.

Comment: Can you cite some references for this?

Comment: subjectAltName is NOT for email addresses.  It's for additional domains and IPs that the certificate is valid for.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#page-25
"Legacy implementations exist where email address is in the subject distinguished name... Conforming implementations ... with email addresses MUST use ... the subject alternative name..."